# How to return text data as output after oversampling using SMOTE?

Tags: python, imblearn

I have a multi class text data which I want to `SMOTE` because of the minority labels. I already did this, but I'm getting sparce matrix as my output.

Is there a way to get the text data back after SMOTE?

Here is my code sample:

```
X_train = df['transcript']
y_train = df['label']
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE 
sm = SMOTE(random_state = 2) 
X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: Thanks, I've made adjustment to my code. the data is in a dataframe with two columns: label and transcript. I've already done the cleaning. But some label are minor that's why I need to SMOTE it. Aside from the cleaning, I haven't done anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `SMOTE` expects `X` to be numerical data only. This is not the problem with the labels, which can be strings.

Read [here](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/over_sampling.html#mathematical-formulation) to understand how SMOTE works internally. Basically it creates a synthetic datapoint for minority class using the convex combination of chosen neighbours.

So, convert your text data (transcripts) into numericals using `TfidfVectorizer` or `CountVectorizer`. You could use the `inverse_transform` method of these vectorizers to get back the text, but the problem is that you would loose the order of words.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'transcripts': ['I want to check this',
                                    'how about one more sentence',
                                    'hopefully this works well fr you',
                                    'I want to check this',
                                    'This is the last sentence or transcript'],
                    'labels': ['good','bad', 'bad', 'good','bad']})
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(df['transcripts'])

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE 
sm = SMOTE(k_neighbors=1, random_state = 2) 
X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_sample(X, df.labels) 


vec.inverse_transform(X_train_res)
# [array(['this', 'check', 'to', 'want'], dtype='<U10'),
#  array(['sentence', 'more', 'one', 'about', 'how'], dtype='<U10'),
#  array(['you', 'fr', 'well', 'works', 'hopefully', 'this'], dtype='<U10'),
#  array(['this', 'check', 'to', 'want'], dtype='<U10'),
#  array(['transcript', 'or', 'last', 'the', 'is', 'sentence', 'this'],
#        dtype='<U10'),
#  array(['want', 'to', 'check', 'this'], dtype='<U10')]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this... this works. I want to have the `vec.inverse_transform(X_train_res)` in a dataframe with respective labels after tranforming. ls that possible?

Answer (score 2):

`SMOTE.fit_sample` uses `label_binarize` from Scikit-learn internally: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/12b2e0d/imblearn/base.py#L87

You should manually use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer` on the `y` values before applying `SMOTE`.

```py
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

sm = SMOTE(random_state = 2)
lb = LabelBinarizer()
y_train_bin = lb.fit_transform(y_train)
X_train_res, y_train_res_bin = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train_bin)
```

Then you can recover the text labels from the fitted `LabelBinarizer.inverse_transform` method:

```py
y_train_res = lb.inverse_transform(y_train_res_bin)
```

Comment: I've tried this before too, but I was getting an error that says: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: This line: 'X_train_res, y_train_res_bin = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train_bin)'